# How do I solve this SQL query problem using Python?

Tags: python, mysql

When I run the following code I get the message "mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where AccNo=?' at line 1". The code is:

```
import mysql.connector
mydb=mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='**********', database='bank_management', auth_plugin='mysql_native_password')

def OpenAcc():
    n=input("Enter The Name: ")
    ac=input("Enter The Account No: ")
    db=input("Enter The Date Of Birth: ")
    add=input("Enter The Address: ")
    cn=input("Enter THe Contact Number: ")
    ob=int(input("Enter The Opening Balance: "))
    data1=(n,ac,db,add,cn,ob)
    data2=(n,ac,ob)
    sql1=('insert into account values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)')
    sql2= ('insert into amount values (%s, %s, %s)')
    x=mydb.cursor()
    x.execute(sql1,data1)
    x.execute(sql2,data2)
    mydb.commit()
    print('Data Entered Successfully.')
    main()

def DepoAmo():
    amount=int(input("Enter the amount you want to deposit: "))
    ac=input("Enter The Account No: ")
    a='select Balance from amount where AccNo=%s'
    data=(ac,)
    x=mydb.cursor(prepared=True)
    x.execute(a,data)
    result=x.fetchone()
    t=result[0] + amount
    sql= 'update amount set Balance where AccNo=%s'
    d=(t, ac)
    x.execute(sql,d)
    mydb.commit()
    main()

def withdrawAmount():
    amount = int(input('Enter the amount you want to withdraw: '))
    ac = input("Enter The Account No: ")
    a = 'select balance from amount where AccNo=%s'
    data = (ac,)
    x = mydb.cursor()
    x.execute(a, data)
    result = x.fetchone()
    t = result[0] - amount
    sql = ('update amount set Balance where AccNo=%s')
    d = (t, ac)
    x.execute(sql, d)
    mydb.commit()
    main()

def BalEnq():
    ac=input("Enter the account no: ")
    a='select * from amount where AccNo=%s'
    data=(ac,)
    x=mydb.cursor()
    x.execute(a,data)
    result=x.fetchone()
    print("Balance for account:",ac,"is",result[-1])
    main()

def DisDetails():
    ac = input("Enter the account no: ")
    a = 'select * from account where AccNo=%s'
    data = (ac,)
    x = mydb.cursor()
    x.execute(a, data)
    result = x.fetchone()
    for i in result:
        print(i)
    main()

def CloseAcc():
    ac = input("Enter the account no: ")
    sql1='delete from account where AccNo=%s'
    sql2='delete from amount where AccNo=%s'
    data=(ac,)
    x=mydb.cursor()
    x.execute(sql1,data)
    x.execute(sql2,data)
    mydb.commit()
    main()


def main():
    print('''
                1. OPEN NEW ACCOUNT
                2. DEPOSIT AMOUNT
                3. WITHDRAW AMOUNT
                4. BALANCE ENQUIRY
                5. DISPLAY CUSTOMER DETAILS
                6. CLOSE AN ACCOUNT''')
    choice =input("Enter The Task You Want To Perform: ")
    if(choice=='1'):
        OpenAcc()
    elif(choice=='2'):
        DepoAmo()
    elif(choice=='3'):
        withdrawAmount()
    elif(choice=='4'):
        BalEnq()
    elif(choice=='5'):
        DisDetails()
    elif(choice=='6'):
        CloseAcc()
    else:
        print("Invalid Choice")
        main()
main()
```

The error message appears when I try to run the code for adding or withdrawing money.  Can anyone see where I am going wrong? I think the error might be related to this line:     a = 'select balance from amount where AccNo=%s'. There are two tables in the bank_management database: account and amount. The account table has 6 headings called Name, AccNo, DOB, Address, ContractNo, and OpeningBal. The amount table has three headings:  Name, AccNo, Balance. If prepared=True is taken out of x=mydb.cursor() the following error appears: mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Comment: Typo.  You have `update amount set Balance`, but you didn't tell it what balance to assign.  I assume you wanted `update amount set Balance=%s ...`.

Comment: DO NOT use recursion to recall `main`.  Instead, use a `while True:` loop, and use `break` when you want to exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

In your deposit method, the sql should be like:
Set Balance=%s where accNo=%s

Same issue in withdraw amount method

Comment: Set Balance=%s where accNo=%s was the answer